# How to grep a string in multiple files on basis of month

Tags: grep, file-search

I have a set of multiple log files and i want to search specific strings from those multiple log files between time period say July to October 2015. 
Please note there are multiple log files for each month like,

```
test.log.2015-07-01.1
test.log.2015-07-01.2
test.log.2015-07-01.3
test.log.2015-10-31.4
test.log.2015-12-01.5
test.log.2016-02-28.6
```

and so on...

Now I am looking for usage log between July-2015 to October-2015 only. 
Currently, I am using below `grep` command.

```
grep -E 'importcoursecustomization|importnoncoursecustomization' test1.log.2015-07-01
```

How do I use this and search for multiple strings for usage log between July-2015 to October-2015 only?

Comment: Make up your mind. Is it July and October? September and October? Or July to October?

Comment: July to October

Comment: Then please edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E 'importcoursecustomization|importnoncoursecustomization' test1.log.2015-[0,1][7,0]-[0-9][0-9].*
```

Here First and second `[01][09]` for month selection on September and October  (note that it would also match on `00` and `19` but thankfully they're not valid month numbers) and last two is for day selection.

Comment: Thanks @Bhaumik 
    grep -E 'importcoursecustomization|importnoncoursecustomization' test1.log.2015-[0,1][0,7]-[0-9][0-9]
Here, [0,1][0,7] is month ?
eg. test.log.2015-[0,7][0,10]-[0-9][0-9] for July to Oct 2015 ?

Comment: I have to grep strings in logs for July - Oct 2015
Is this correct ?
grep -E 'importcoursecustomization|importnoncoursecustomization' test1.log.2015-[0,1][0,7]-[0-9][0-9].* > grep_logs.txt